# Creating a raster of percent of pixel occupied from shapefile

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, area

Starting from a polygon shapefile, How can I produce a 1km raster, where the cell values are the percentage of the pixel occupied by the shapefile. For example the values would range from 0 to 100%. I would like to use freely available python tools like osgeo, shapely, rasterstats etc to produce the output raster and it needs to be an efficient solution because it is a global extent 1km calculation.[image]

Comment: At its core, this seems to be a basic question about how to get a percent coverage between two vector layers (I don't think you're going to be able to do this with raster pixels), fanned out across millions of polygons. The added criteria of "efficient solution" will make this difficult to answer, at least without knowing what you've tried.

Comment: The resulting output needs to be a 1km raster. What I have tried is creating an extremely large 1km vector fishnet, then using a percent coverage between the two vector layers and converting the tabular output to a raster. There must be a better way to make this calculation.

Comment: I would do it exactly the way you just described. I'm with @phloem. I really can't think of a more efficient method that involves using the raster cells themselves.

Comment: @john_z you can likely save yourself some pain by preprocessing your blue polygons to remove internal boundaries and simplify the outside to remove unnecessary vertices.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function I wrote that does exactly this, except the grid is defined by an input raster **and** my polygon was not a MultiPolygon, and it had no holes. In your case, "geom" would be your blue shapefile, and you need to specify the xs and ys of your 1km grid. Currently, those values are being read from the underlying raster object (fsrc). At the end of the code, you'll need to replace gt[0]*gt[4] with your cell resolution. I believe the "geom" object is a shapely geometry, but I'm not certain. It's whatever rasterstats returns in its main code body in the following line: `geom = shape(feat['geometry'])`.

Note that your grid and your polygon had better be in the same projection.

```
def fractional_pixel_weights(fsrc, geom):

""" 
Returns a grid of the same size as fsrc, where each value represents the
fraction of the cell that is filled by the polygon in geom.

fsrc is a rasterstats-created object (I think rasterio).
"""

gt = fsrc.affine
xs = np.arange(gt[2], gt[2] +  gt[0]* (1 + fsrc.shape[1]), gt[0])
ys = np.arange(gt[5], gt[5] +  gt[4]* (1 + fsrc.shape[0]), gt[4])

# Convert geom into ogr geometry
geom_ogr = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(geom.to_wkt())

# Loop through each grid cell, compute the intersecting area
overlapping_areas = np.empty((len(ys)-1, len(xs)-1))
for ix in range(len(xs)-1):
    xmin = xs[ix]
    xmax = xs[ix + 1]
    for iy in range(len(ys)-1):
        ymax = ys[iy]
        ymin = ys[iy + 1]

        # Intersecting area
        coords_wkt = "POLYGON ((" + str(xmin) + ' ' + str(ymax) + ', ' + str(xmax) + ' ' + str(ymax) + ', ' + str(xmax) + ' ' + str(ymin) + ', ' + str(xmin) + ' ' + str(ymin) + ', ' + str(xmin) + ' ' + str(ymax) + "))"
        polycell = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(coords_wkt)

        overlapping_areas[iy, ix] = polycell.Intersection(geom_ogr).Area()

# Ratio of overlapped area to pixel area
frac_intersected = overlapping_areas / (abs(gt[0] * gt[4]))

return frac_intersected
```

This isn't a complete answer because, as stated, it uses an underlying raster to create the grid, but hopefully it's a good enough start for you to implement what you want.

I also just realized that you have what looks like a MultiPolygon shapefile. I would follow the other answer-er's advice and dissolve it first into one.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to optimize (speed, cpu, memory etc)

One option would be to

1) rasterize your polygons - cells completely within/outside the polygons are accurately set, cells on the edge are not

2) disolve the polygons to get rid of boundaries between polygons (it doesn't have to be just 1 polygon, but as few as possible)

3) in code, create one square polygon having the same size as one raster cell.

4) loop through each of your disolved polygon, move the square polygon along the polygon's edge (aligned on cells coordinate) and compute the overlap.